# Magento customer can't login and checkout

Tags: magento

I have a problem with my webisite.

When I go to checkout, it redirects and nothing happens.

My webiste: http://jdarts.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/

Comment: It would help us more easily help you if you describe your problem here in more detail. Also, please show what you have done to try to solve the problem so far, and any code you think is relevant. Please don't expect us to go to your site AND find AND solve your problems. That being said, I get a "Not Found" message through your link so I can't even see your website.

Comment: Sorry, i will write more detial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your checkout page. I have visited it. Only issue I see is all of your URL's missing index.php. If you modify url in browser with index.php then it start working.

You might have tried to remove index.php from url by setting up "Use Web Server Rewrites" to YES in System->Configuration->General->Web->Search Engine Optimization in magento backend but missed to rewrite index.php in .htaccess

check this line in your .htacces in magento root

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Quick fix will be that you use index.php in URL's by setting "Use Web Server Rewrites" to NO

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but even modify url in browser with index.php,it also can't jump to setp 2(* i use checkout by guest),

Comment: bcz ajax url's dont have index.php in its url.  check my updated answer again

Comment: Sorry, i write more detail about this:                                  step1: i go to http://jdarts.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/                  setp2: click check out as guest                                             step3: it redirect to http://jdarts.com/checkout/cart/ i change it to         http://jdarts.com/index.php/checkout/cart/                           step4: it go to http://jdarts.com/index.php/checkout/cart/ not is step 2

Comment: I'm telling you same thing again. It is because js is firing ajax request which do not have index.php in url. So first resolve index.php issue as explained in my reply then everything will work fine.

Comment: Hi, is Rewrite issue there, check this link and you will see that all is working fine, you just need to enable the Rewrite mode.  http://jdarts.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

Comment: Thanks Deependra Singh,Dario, that is the problem